# text with margin on the right to stay auto on every resolution

Tags: html, css

I'm new to creating websites and sorry for my stupid question. I want my text in border to be a little bit on the right and in any resolution of the page remains similar without fixed where any previous
Tгanks in advice

Answer (score 0):

You can apply following css to the text for border

```
border: 1px solid;
```

And regarding your right alignment you can user float :

```
float : right;
```

Example : -

```
<p style="border: 1px solid; float : right; text-align: center;">Text with border</p>
```

Comment: My idea is to have an auto orientation but the <div> with the content to be somehow in the center, the float:right is sending it too much to the right

Comment: Well i would say you can user the following for aligining it to the center of your div : - <div style="border: 1px solid; float : right; text-align: center;">Text with border</div>                                         see my previous answer i have added the align tag to it